# Initialize parent ViewModel property from usercontrol datacontext property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I am trying to initialize parent `ViewModel` property from `usercontrol` property.. below are the snaps ... i want to initialize parent "one" and "Two" property by the usercontrol if the property is `null` or `vice-versa`

**window.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="wpfParentUserControlDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpfParentUserControlDemo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="369.737" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ParentViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,-4">        
        <local:UserControl1 DataContext="{Binding One}" Margin="288,49,22,240"></local:UserControl1>
        <local:UserControl1 DataContext="{Binding Two}" Margin="10,49,283,240"></local:UserControl1>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace wpfParentUserControlDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class ParentViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private DemoConnectionViewModel _One;

        public DemoConnectionViewModel One
        {
            get { return _One; }
            set { _One = value; }
        }

        private DemoConnectionViewModel _Two;

        public DemoConnectionViewModel Two
        {
            get { return _Two; }
            set { _Two = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

**UserControl1.Xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="wpfParentUserControlDemo.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpfParentUserControlDemo"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Connections}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ></ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**UserControl1.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace wpfParentUserControlDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (this.DataContext == null)
            {
                var ViewModel = new DemoUserMainViewModel();
                ViewModel.Connections = new ObservableCollection<DemoConnectionViewModel>();
                ViewModel.Connections.Add(new DemoConnectionViewModel { Name = "A", Type = SqlDbType.BigInt });
                ViewModel.Connections.Add(new DemoConnectionViewModel { Name = "B", Type = SqlDbType.Bit });
                ViewModel.Connections.Add(new DemoConnectionViewModel { Name = "C", Type = SqlDbType.NVarChar });

                this.DataContext = ViewModel;
            }
        }
    }

    public class DemoUserMainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<DemoConnectionViewModel> _Connections;

        public ObservableCollection<DemoConnectionViewModel> Connections
        {
            get { return _Connections; }
            set { _Connections = value; }
        }
    }

    public class DemoConnectionViewModel : BaseViewModel, IDataConnection
    {
        private string _Name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set { _Name = value; }
        }

        private SqlDbType _Type;

        public SqlDbType Type
        {
            get { return _Type; }
            set { _Type = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

**IDataConnection.cs**

```
using System.Data;

namespace wpfParentUserControlDemo
{
    public interface IDataConnection
    {  
        string Name { get; set; }
        SqlDbType Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: So why are you setting the DataContext property of UserControl1 in the constructor?

Comment: @mm8 Because i am sending null for datacontext property

Comment: So you want to set the One and Two properties of the ParentViewModel in the constructor of UserControl1 or what is your question?

Comment: @mm8 yes .. updated the question please check

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but if you want to check whether the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` has been set, you should wait until it has been loaded.

You could then access the `DataContext` of the parent window using the `Window.GetWindow` method:

```
public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (this.DataContext == null)
        {
            MainWindow parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this) as MainWindow;
            if (parentWindow != null)
            {
                ParentViewModel parentViewModel = parentWindow.DataContext as ParentViewModel;
                if (parentViewModel != null)
                {
                    //set One or Two or do whatever you want to do here...
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```